# Show distinct records, remove duplicates from xml document using xslt

Tags: xslt

I have an xml document from that I have to remove duplicate `<itemGrp>` based on
`<rateclass>` value.

If there are multiple `<itemGrp>` with the same `<rateclass>` exclude all except 1 `<itemGrp>`

Including xml and xslt, The results can be seen at http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html

by pasting the xml and xslt

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:a="http://xml.amadeus.com/FQDRES_12_1_1A"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:vbs="urn:schemas-sqlxml-org:vbs">
    <!-- Main Template -->
    <xsl:template match="/Responses">
        <xsl:element name="Fares">
            <xsl:for-each select="./RequestResponse/Fare_DisplayFaresForCityPairReply">
                <xsl:for-each select="./a:flightDetails">

                    <!-- inside each flight details, we want to get all of the item groups-->
                    <xsl:for-each select="./a:itemGrp">
                        <!-- if rateclass repeating then skip this record other wise add this record to output file-->
                        <xsl:element name="Calss">
                            <xsl:value-of select="./a:fareQualifItem/a:additionalFareDetails/a:rateClass"/>
                        </xsl:element>                           
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
   <Responses>
      <RequestResponse>    
        <Fare_DisplayFaresForCityPairReply xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <flightDetails xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/FQDRES_12_1_1A">
            <itemGrp>
              <fareQualifItem>
                <additionalFareDetails>
                  <rateClass>XK2DCA</rateClass>
                </additionalFareDetails>
                <discountDetails>
                  <fareQualifier>725</fareQualifier>
                </discountDetails>
              </fareQualifItem>
            </itemGrp>
           <itemGrp>
              <fareQualifItem>
                <additionalFareDetails>
                  <rateClass>XK2DCAB</rateClass>
                </additionalFareDetails>
                <discountDetails>
                  <fareQualifier>725</fareQualifier>
                </discountDetails>
              </fareQualifItem>
            </itemGrp>
            <itemGrp>
              <fareQualifItem>
                <additionalFareDetails>
                  <rateClass>XK2DCA</rateClass>
                </additionalFareDetails>
                <discountDetails>
                  <fareQualifier>725</fareQualifier>
                </discountDetails>
              </fareQualifItem>
            </itemGrp>
    </flightDetails>
     <flightDetails xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/FQDRES_12_1_1A">
         <itemGrp>
              <fareQualifItem>
                <additionalFareDetails>
                  <rateClass>AAXK2DCA</rateClass>
                </additionalFareDetails>
                <discountDetails>
                  <fareQualifier>725</fareQualifier>
                </discountDetails>
              </fareQualifItem>
            </itemGrp>
           <itemGrp>
              <fareQualifItem>
                <additionalFareDetails>
                  <rateClass>BXK2DCAB</rateClass>
                </additionalFareDetails>
                <discountDetails>
                  <fareQualifier>725</fareQualifier>
                </discountDetails>
              </fareQualifItem>
            </itemGrp>
            <itemGrp>
              <fareQualifItem>
                <additionalFareDetails>
                  <rateClass>AAXK2DCA</rateClass>
                </additionalFareDetails>
                <discountDetails>
                  <fareQualifier>725</fareQualifier>
                </discountDetails>
              </fareQualifItem>
            </itemGrp>               
    </flightDetails>
    </Fare_DisplayFaresForCityPairReply>
  </RequestResponse>
</Responses>
```

The response is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Fares>
   <Calss>XK2DCA</Calss>
   <Calss>XK2DCAB</Calss>
   <Calss>XK2DCA</Calss>
   <Calss>AAXK2DCA</Calss>
   <Calss>BXK2DCAB</Calss>
   <Calss>AAXK2DCA</Calss>
</Fares>
```

What I want is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Fares>
   <Calss>XK2DCA</Calss>
   <Calss>XK2DCAB</Calss>   
   <Calss>AAXK2DCA</Calss>
   <Calss>BXK2DCAB</Calss>   
</Fares>
```

Thanks for the answer Michael. could've been solved:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="http://xml.amadeus.com/FQDRES_12_1_1A" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:vbs="urn:schemas-sqlxml-org:vbs" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">
   <!-- Main Template -->
   <xsl:key name="rateClass" match="/Responses/RequestResponse/Fare_DisplayFaresForCityPairReply/a:flightDetails/a:itemGrp/a:fareQualifItem/a:additionalFareDetails/a:rateClass/text()" use="." />
   <xsl:template match="/Responses">
      <xsl:element name="Fares">
         <xsl:for-each select="./RequestResponse/Fare_DisplayFaresForCityPairReply">
            <xsl:for-each select="./a:flightDetails">
               <!-- inside each flight details, we want to get all of the item groups-->
               <xsl:for-each select="./a:itemGrp">
                  <!-- if rateclass repeating then skip this record other wise add this record to output file-->
                  <xsl:variable name="ItemGroup_Items" select="." />
                  <!--<xsl:variable name="rateClass_1" select="./a:fareQualifItem/a:additionalFareDetails/a:rateClass"/>
                <xsl:if test="vbs:CheckExists($rateClass_1) = 'FALSE'">-->
                  <xsl:for-each select="./a:fareQualifItem/a:additionalFareDetails/a:rateClass/text()[generate-id()= generate-id(key('rateClass',.)[1])]">
                     <xsl:element name="Calss">
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                     </xsl:element>
                      <xsl:element name="Value_from_itemGrp">
                        <xsl:value-of select="($ItemGroup_Items/a:fareQualifItem/a:additionalFareDetails/a:rateClass)"/>
                      </xsl:element>
                  </xsl:for-each>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'd  suggest you minimize the example to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem. In general, removing duplicates in XSLT 2.0 can be achieved either by [grouping](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping) or by using the [distinct-values()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-distinct-values) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your latest XML input, the expected output can be achieved quite simply by:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:a="http://xml.amadeus.com/FQDRES_12_1_1A"
exclude-result-prefixes="a">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Responses">
    <Fares>
        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(RequestResponse/Fare_DisplayFaresForCityPairReply/a:flightDetails/a:itemGrp/a:fareQualifItem/a:additionalFareDetails/a:rateClass)">
            <Calss>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </Calss>
        </xsl:for-each>  
    </Fares>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael I am off now once I get back tomorrow will test and mark as answer.

Comment: throws me an error : XslTransformException
---------------------
'distinct-values()' is an unknown XSLT function.

Comment: Apparently you're not using an XSLT 2.0 processor. If so, why is your stylesheet tagged as `version="2.0"`?

Comment: honestly I thought it was 2.0 style :(

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you actually using (in production, not for testing)?

Comment: I am using the same xslt for testing/production

Comment: I am asking about the **processor**, not the stylesheet. If you're not sure, here's how to find out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-we-check-that-which-xslt-processor-uses-as-default-in-solr/25245033#25245033